# sftp package for TCL

Tags: tcl

I do not have a background in TCL. I was told that one of our FTP scripts is required to be converted to SFTP for security reasons.  This script basically goes to an FTP server and grabs a file and puts in in another location.

Is there an sftp package available for tcl that I can implement without having to rewrite the entire script in a language I know nothing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to modify an existing TCL script that makes an FTP call, and you wish to replace that FTP call with an SFTP call - is that right? If so, and assuming the TCL script simply makes an `exec` call to FTP, then it should be a very straightforward change to switch to SFTP. See [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14705) for example.

If on the other hand, your existing script is using the [TCLlib FTP package](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/ftp-docs/), then I'm not so sure if there is such a straightforward change, as I'm not aware of an SFTP package in TCL. I would imagine it is tricky to get the FTP package working over TLS/SSL. Of course, you could use Expect - there are [dozens of examples online](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=expect%20sftp).

Comment: it is using the ftp package                                     package require ftp
package require mime
package require smtp

Comment: @user1086526 then, as I mentioned, your options are either: try and get the existing script working with TLS/SSL (could be tricky) or rewrite using one of the Expect examples.

Comment: Actually, maybe it's not so hard to get the FTP package to work with TLS, see an attempt here http://objectmix.com/tcl/390455-ftp-ssl-tls-nd-tcllib-what-best-way-do-sftp.html

Comment: SFTP is a different protocol entirely to FTP+SSL. It's really an application of SSH.

Comment: @user1086526 - did you find a solution or do you need more advice?